# SQL Server: How to get/save result of "statistics profile"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I find out the option `set statistics profile on` is very useful for me, so I would like to save results of that to table. However, after some research in the internet I did not find any chance to save it after execution automatically. And I start to think about parsing of xml plan and find the following link [SQL Server – Practical SQL Server XML: Part One – Query Plan Cache and Cost of Operations in the Cache](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/17/sql-server-practical-sql-server-xml-part-one-query-plan-cache-and-cost-of-operations-in-the-cache/).

The query there is quite appropriate for me... but it will be better if it looks exactly like a result of `set statistics profile on`. If you have a good parsing plan query or you know how to save results of `statistics profile` to table, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to save the statistics profile result to a table is by saving the SSMS grid result to a file, and then importing into a table with a Powershell script.  Below is an example script for SQL Server 2014.   Make sure the "include column headers..." and "quote strings containing list separators..." options are specified under Tools-->Options--->Query Results-->SQL Server-->Results to Grid.

Save the statistics profile output to a file by right-clicking on the grid result, select "Save results..." and select the CSV type.  Then run the Powershell script, specifying the desired server name, file name and table name.  This script will recreate the table upon every execution, but you could can customize it for your needs.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string]$ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=StatisticsProfileImport",
    [string]$StatProfileFileName = "C:\Temp\statistics_profile.csv",    
    [string]$StatProfileTableName = "dbo.StatisticsProfile"
)

Function Create-Table()
{

    $createTableStatement = @("IF(OBJECT_ID(N'$StatProfileTableName ', 'U')) IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE $StatProfileTableName;
    CREATE TABLE $StatProfileTableName(
         Rows   bigint
        ,Executes bigint
        ,StmtText nvarchar(MAX)
        ,StmtId int
        ,NodeId int
        ,Parent int
        ,PhysicalOp nvarchar(100)
        ,LogicalOp nvarchar(100)
        ,Argument nvarchar(MAX)
        ,DefinedValues nvarchar(MAX)
        ,EstimateRows float
        ,EstimateIO float
        ,EstimateCPU float
        ,AvgRowSize float
        ,TotalSubtreeCost float
        ,OutputList nvarchar(MAX)
        ,Warnings nvarchar(MAX)
        ,Type nvarchar(100)
        ,Parallel int
        ,EstimateExecutions bigint
        );");

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString;
    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $createTableStatement;
    $command.Connection = $connection;
    $connection.Open();
    $null = $command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    $connection.Close();

}

Function Get-SqlIntParameterValue($value)
{
    if(( $value -eq "NULL") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {[System.DBNull]::Value} else {[System.Int32]::Parse($value)};
}
Function Get-SqlBigIntParameterValue($value)
{
    if(( $value -eq "NULL") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {[System.DBNull]::Value} else {[System.Int64]::Parse($value)};
}
Function Get-SqlStringParameterValue($value)
{
    if(( $value -eq "NULL") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {[System.DBNull]::Value} else {$value};
}
Function Get-SqlFloatParameterValue($value)
{
    if(( $value -eq "NULL") -or [System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {[System.DBNull]::Value} else {[System.Double]::Parse($value)};
}

Function Create-Insert-Command()
{

    $insertStatement = @("INSERT INTO $StatProfileTableName VALUES(
          @Rows
        , @Executes
        , @StmtText
        , @StmtId
        , @NodeId
        , @Parent
        , @PhysicalOp
        , @LogicalOp
        , @Argument
        , @DefinedValues
        , @EstimateRows
        , @EstimateIO
        , @EstimateCPU
        , @AvgRowSize
        , @TotalSubtreeCost
        , @OutputList
        , @Warnings
        , @Type
        , @Parallel
        , @EstimateExecutions
        );");

    $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $insertStatement;
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@Rows", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::BigInt);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@Executes", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::BigInt);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@StmtText", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@StmtId", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@NodeId", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@Parent", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@PhysicalOp", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 100);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@LogicalOp", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 100);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@Argument", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@DefinedValues", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@EstimateRows", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Float);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@EstimateIO", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Float);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@EstimateCPU", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Float);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@AvgRowSize", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Float);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@TotalSubtreeCost", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Float);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@OutputList", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@Warnings", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@Type", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, 100);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@Parallel", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int);
    $null = $command.Parameters.Add("@EstimateExecutions", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::BigInt);

    return $command;

}

Function Assign-Parameter-Values($insertCommand, $statProfileRecord)
{

    $insertCommand.Parameters["@Rows"].Value = Get-SqlBigIntParameterValue($statProfileRecord.Rows);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@Executes"].Value = Get-SqlBigIntParameterValue($statProfileRecord.Executes);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@StmtText"].Value = Get-SqlStringParameterValue($statProfileRecord.StmtText);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@StmtId"].Value = Get-SqlIntParameterValue($statProfileRecord.StmtId);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@NodeId"].Value = Get-SqlIntParameterValue($statProfileRecord.NodeId);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@Parent"].Value = Get-SqlIntParameterValue($statProfileRecord.Parent);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@PhysicalOp"].Value = Get-SqlStringParameterValue($statProfileRecord.PhysicalOp);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@LogicalOp"].Value = Get-SqlStringParameterValue($statProfileRecord.LogicalOp);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@Argument"].Value = Get-SqlStringParameterValue($statProfileRecord.Argument);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@DefinedValues"].Value = Get-SqlStringParameterValue($statProfileRecord.DefinedValues);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@EstimateRows"].Value = Get-SqlFloatParameterValue($statProfileRecord.EstimateRows);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@EstimateIO"].Value = Get-SqlFloatParameterValue($statProfileRecord.EstimateIO);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@EstimateCPU"].Value = Get-SqlFloatParameterValue($statProfileRecord.EstimateCPU);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@AvgRowSize"].Value = Get-SqlFloatParameterValue($statProfileRecord.AvgRowSize);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@TotalSubtreeCost"].Value = Get-SqlFloatParameterValue($statProfileRecord.TotalSubtreeCost);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@OutputList"].Value = Get-SqlStringParameterValue($statProfileRecord.OutputList);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@Warnings"].Value = Get-SqlStringParameterValue($statProfileRecord.Warnings);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@Type"].Value = Get-SqlStringParameterValue($statProfileRecord.Type);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@Parallel"].Value = Get-SqlIntParameterValue($statProfileRecord.Parallel);
    $insertCommand.Parameters["@EstimateExecutions"].Value = Get-SqlBigIntParameterValue($EstimateExecutions.EstimateExecutions);

}

### main ###

Create-Table;
$insertCommand = Create-Insert-Command;

$statProfile = Import-Csv $StatProfileFileName;
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString;
$insertCommand.Connection = $connection;
$connection.Open();

foreach($statProfileRecord in $statProfile)
{

    Assign-Parameter-Values $insertCommand $statProfileRecord;
    $null = $insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}

$connection.Close();
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want. As you noted, there're plenty of ways how to save results from SSMS. I give you more information,eg: I have an application and I have performance issue in DB level. Yes, I'm able to check DMV and get execution plans from that and so on, but I asking about “how to get data like ‘statistics profile’ or script that shows data looks like this from execution plan”. Commonly, I know how to get this info with .NET application–just add `statistics profile` to query and process second resultset. This way is extremely hard, so I try to find more ‘dynamic’ and simpler way.